# How chain sleep command in docker compose?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, wait

Consider a snippet:

```
---
version: '3.4'
services:
  app:
    image: my_image
    command: ["sleep", "60s", "&&", "my_command"]
```

Gives me:

```
sleep: invalid time interval вЂ�my_commandвЂ™
Try 'sleep --help' for more information.
```

What is wrong? Why did this happen?

```
Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc
Host OS - windows 10
```

Answer (score 15):

You may use it like this to run `sleep 60` followed by your command:

```
---
version: '3.4'
services:
  app:
    image: my_image
  command: sh -c "
     sleep 60 &&
     my_command"
```

When you run `command: ["sleep", "60s", "&&", "my_command"]` it passes all the arguments from position 2 onwards to `sleep` command. It is actually attempting to run your command as:

```
sleep '60s' '&&' 'uname'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using older version of docker-compose that you can try this.

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  foo:
    image: alpine
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
          echo "sleep for 10sec"
          sleep 10 
          your_command
```

Comment: This should just be the default usage in the documentation, not the `[]` approach